# bootstrap dropdown doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using dropdown functionality of bootstrap and I have this dropdown in container, but in outside I have wrapper, which is reacting on the same event (onclick), so I do

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

because I don't want to react on event in wrapper, when I'm clicking dropdown button. Unfortunately, this code also stops my dropdown event. Is it possible to avoid this behaviour and display only dropdown list, without alert? 
https://jsfiddle.net/hms5265s/

Comment: Just add your `e.stopPropagation()` into the wrapper function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if($(e.target).is("#dropdown")){
    alert('work');
  }
  else{
    e.stopPropagation();}
});
```

Comment: This doesn't help at all. The statement is wrong and also both cases are useless

Comment: @stwosch tell me the what exactly you want?

Comment: I want to display opened dropdown without called alert in wrapper

Comment: @stwoch means by default you need open drop down whenever you page is loaded?

Comment: No, I want to display it on click event

Comment: document.querySelector('#wrapper').addEventListener('click', () => {
 $('.dropdown-menu, a').click(function(){
   //dostuff
   alert('work');
});
});

Answer (score -1):

If you want your alert to be called on the click event of the wrapper but not the click event of the dropdown iteself you can try something like this

```
document.querySelector('#wrapper').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    var source = event.target || event.srcElement;
console.log(source.id);
if (source.id !== 'someId') {
// do some stuff
    alert("I don't want this alert");
}
// you can stop the even propagation here if you want to.
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hms5265s/10/)

If you also don't want to assign an Id for your dropdown you can also check for a class.

Comment: @Stwosch is this not working or it's not what you want?

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution

```
    Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className){
        tClassName = this.className;
        return tClassName.match(".*[ ]?"+className+"[ ]?.*") ? true : false;
};

document.querySelector('#wrapper').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('clicked' + e.target.hasClass('dropdown-toggle'));
        if(e.target.hasClass('dropdown-toggle')) return

    alert("I don't want this alert");
});

document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hms5265s/6/

updated solution:

```
Element.prototype.hasClass = function(className){
        tClassName = this.className;
        return tClassName.match(".*[ ]?"+className+"[ ]?.*") ? true : false;
};

document.querySelector('#wrapper').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(e.target.hasClass('dropdown-toggle')) return
    alert("I don't want this alert");
});

document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
if(! e.target.hasClass('dropdown-toggle')){
    e.stopPropagation();
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hms5265s/12/

Comment: You are doing stopPropagation on .dropdown-menu, which is <ul>... There is no event